# Python: How to print multiplication table based on two inputs?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a program called multChart(x,y) that prints a multiplication table based on two inputs, one specifying the number of rows to print and another specifying the number of columns. So it would look like this:

```
>>> multChart(4,5):
1: 1 2 3 4 5
2: 2 4 6 8 10
3: 3 6 9 12 15
4: 4 8 12 16 20
```

Here's what my current code looks like:

```
def multChart(x,y):
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        print(i,':',i*1,i*2,i*3,i*4,i*5)
```

I'm totally stuck on how to implement the y value. I also know there should be a better way of printing the multiplication instead of i * multiples of five, but I'm not sure what loop to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's many ways to solve this; one would be to nest a second `for` loop and print the values without newlines; another would be to generate a list or tuple with the needed results in a comprehension and print that (using a spread operator `*` if you don't want the brackets or parentheses); another still would be to generate a string that has the products in it for a whole line before printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def multChart(x,y):
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        print(i, ':', end=" ")
        for j in range(1,y+1):
            print(i*j, end =" ")
        print()

multChart(4,5)
```

produces

```
1 : 1 2 3 4 5
2 : 2 4 6 8 10
3 : 3 6 9 12 15
4 : 4 8 12 16 20
```

You can use a second for loop for the second index. Also, note that you can use end in the print statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need another loop inside your `print` for looping over the `y` range:

```
def multChart(x, y):
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        print(i, ':', *[i * z for z in range(1, y+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def multChart(x,y):
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        print(i,':',*list(map(lambda y: i*y,list(range(1,y+1 ) ) ) ) )
multChart(4,5)
```